# How to filter an array of objects by multiple identical properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, filtering, lodash

[image: How do I filter this array as described in the question]

## Description

Notice that **entry1** and **entry4** share the same **value** for `property: 'subject'` and `property: 'field'`.

## Question

Im looking for a performative and clean way to filter this array and get the entries that share **both** `value`s for those `property`ies.

UPDATE:

## Returned value

I'm not trying to transform the data but analyze it.
so the returned value from the analysis should look like this:

`[['entry1', 'entry4'],...]`

and with this analysis **list** I could easily transform my `triples = [...]` into a list of **triples** where I remove one of entries(doesnt matter which, could be 'entry1' or 'entry4'), and update the other one

```
[
  { subject: "entry1", property: "subject", value: "sport" },
  { subject: "entry1", property: "field", value: "category" },
  { subject: "entry1", property: "content", value: "football" },
  { subject: "entry1", property: "content", value: "basketball" },
]
```

#### P.S

1. **I'm not looking for a solution like**:

   `array.filter(({property, value})=> property === 'sport' && value === 'category')`

I dont know 'sport' or 'category'. **Those are dynamic values.**

2. My actual data is much bigger, and contains much more **property** types for each **entry**. Also its not ordered as nicely as I show here. I did simplify it, so please have in mind performance.

code snippet:

```
const triples = [
  { subject: "entry1", property: "subject", value: "sport" },
  { subject: "entry1", property: "field", value: "category" },
  { subject: "entry1", property: "content", value: "football" },
  
  { subject: "entry4", property: "subject", value: "sport" },
  { subject: "entry4", property: "field", value: "category" },
  { subject: "entry4", property: "content", value: "basketball" },
  
  { subject: "entry2", property: "subject", value: "music" },
  { subject: "entry2", property: "field", value: "category" },
  { subject: "entry2", property: "content", value: "notes" },
  
  { subject: "entry3", property: "subject", value: "painting" },
  { subject: "entry3", property: "field", value: "category" },
  { subject: "entry3", property: "content", value: "drawings" }
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add a snippet of your current approach.

Comment: I'm also unsure about what you want the resulting data structure to look like.

Comment: Take a look on groupBy method of lodash

Comment: @nstanard
It is still a work in progress. and a messy one. I wanna see some different approaches to this.
my try was to first reduce the array into an object by the values.
the for each for more then 1 values run a check, kinda...

Comment: I still need to see what you expect the result to be. Also... it really is frowned upon to ask open ended .... "How would you code this".

Comment: @nstanard
the data structure could be an array of array (1 way).
[['entry1', 'entry4'],...]
I need a way to know which entries should be merge into 1 entry

Comment: @nstanard
I see what you are saying about being "open ended.." . but how would you "model" this kind of question?

I simplified a data model as much as I could in order to hear different approaches to this.

Comment: Can you include the code as text at the question instead of an image? What do you mean by _"merge them later into 1 entry"_? Would `{subject:"entry4", property:"field", value:"category"}` be deleted from the array?

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Copy and code-format the code into the question.

Comment: Your data structure looks badly organised: objects that belong together (3 by 3) should really be encapsulated in a dedicated object. Is this input data structure open for improvement? Or do you need to work with exactly that (for some reason)? Or is your image a wrong representation of the real data structure? Maybe it is a nested array?

Comment: Hey @ueeiieu - please take a look at my answer. I have mapped the data by entry and we are now just moments away from having you an answer. But I'm still not 100% sure what you need to match one. You want to only match on subject and field... but you dont know what values specifically?

Comment: @trincot
I added an image with highlights so it would be easier to understand the case. 
But I also updated a snippet

Comment: @trincot
This is the data structure I get. I work with graph database and when it comes to graphes the response comes in a triple-like format

Comment: @ueeiieu - Would you please run the snippet I have provided and give feedback on what you are looking for? I am pretty sure I've provided enough information on how to approach this and you should be able to take what I've done and finish it up. I'm also happy to continue to help.

Comment: @nstanard 
I've update my question with a section of **returned value**
to remove the confusion

Comment: Dont forget to approve the answer and upvote if it answered your question and helped you! :)

Comment: Why, in your desired outcome, do you associate "entry1" with "baseball"? Why not not "entry4" with "football"? Is there a logic like "first come first serve" that you require?

Comment: @trincot you’re right. i still wasnt very clear. what’s important here is the merge of the values.  one of the subjects need to be discarded. It doesnt really matter which.

Comment: OK, now I see you would already be happy with a result like `["entry1", "entry4"]`. So I have posted an answer that does just that.

Comment: @ueeiieu, could you give some feed back?

Comment: @trincot 
Your're solution is very nice. I've also added my solution. I want to give it a little bit more time for more approaches before setting the "correct answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say the input data structure is not optimal, and the use of "subject" as both a real object property and as a value *for* `property` will make it all the more confusing. I will call the first notion (the *real* `subject`) "entries", since the sample values are "entry1", "entry2", ....

Here is a way to extract `["entry1", "entry4"]` for your sample data:

1. Group the data by their entry into objects where "property" and "value" are translated into key/value pairs, so you would get something like this:

   ```
   {
       entry1: { subject: "sport", field: "category", content: "football" },
       entry4: { subject: "sport", field: "category", content: "basketball" },
       entry2: { subject: "music", field: "category", content: "notes" },
       entry3: { subject: "painting", field: "category", content: "drawings" }
   }
   ```

   This will be easier to work with. The below code will in fact create a `Map` instead of a plain object, but it is the same principle.
2. Define a new `group` property for these objects, where the value is composed of subject and field, stringified as JSON. For example, the first object of the above result would be extended with:

   ```
   group: '["sport","category"]'
   ```
3. Create a Map of entries, keyed by their group value. So that would give this result:

   ```
   {
       '["sport","category"]': ["entry1","entry4"],
       '["music","category"]': ["entry2"],
       '["painting","category"]': ["entry3"]
   }
   ```
4. Now it is a simple step to only list the values (the subarrays) and only those that have more than one entry value.

Here is the implementation:

```js
const triples = [{subject: "entry1", property: "subject", value: "sport"},{subject: "entry1", property: "field", value: "category"},{subject: "entry1", property: "content", value: "football"},{subject: "entry4", property: "subject", value: "sport"},{subject: "entry4", property: "field", value: "category"},{subject: "entry4", property: "content", value: "basketball"},{subject: "entry2", property: "subject", value: "music"},{subject: "entry2", property: "field", value: "category"},{subject: "entry2", property: "content", value: "notes"},{subject: "entry3", property: "subject", value: "painting"},{subject: "entry3", property: "field", value: "category"},{subject: "entry3", property: "content", value: "drawings"},];

// 1. Group the data by subject into objects where "property" and "value" are translated into key/value pairs:
const entries = new Map(triples.map(o => [o.subject, { entry: o.subject }]));
triples.forEach(o => entries.get(o.subject)[o.property] = o.value);
// 2. Define a group value for these objects (composed of subject and field)
entries.forEach(o => o.group = JSON.stringify([o.subject, o.field]));
// 3. Create Map of entries, keyed by their group value
const groups = new Map(Array.from(entries.values(), o => [o.group, []]));
entries.forEach(o => groups.get(o.group).push(o.entry));
// 4. Keep only the subarrays that have more than one value
const result = [...groups.values()].filter(group => group.length > 1);
console.log(result);
```

Be aware that the output is a nested array, because in theory there could be more combined entries, like `[ ["entry1", "entry4"], ["entry123", "entry521", "entry951"] ]`

The above can be modified/extended to get the final filtered result. In the third step you would still collect the objects (not just the entry value), and the filtered result is then mapped back to the original format:

```js
const triples = [{subject: "entry1", property: "subject", value: "sport"},{subject: "entry1", property: "field", value: "category"},{subject: "entry1", property: "content", value: "football"},{subject: "entry4", property: "subject", value: "sport"},{subject: "entry4", property: "field", value: "category"},{subject: "entry4", property: "content", value: "basketball"},{subject: "entry2", property: "subject", value: "music"},{subject: "entry2", property: "field", value: "category"},{subject: "entry2", property: "content", value: "notes"},{subject: "entry3", property: "subject", value: "painting"},{subject: "entry3", property: "field", value: "category"},{subject: "entry3", property: "content", value: "drawings"},];

// 1. Group the data by subject into objects where "property" and "value" are translated into key/value pairs:
const entries = new Map(triples.map(o => [o.subject, { entry: o.subject }]));
triples.forEach(o => entries.get(o.subject)[o.property] = o.value);
// 2. Define a group value for these objects (composed of subject and field)
entries.forEach(o => o.group = JSON.stringify([o.subject, o.field]));
// 3. Create Map of objects(*), keyed by their group value
const groups = new Map(Array.from(entries.values(), o => [o.group, []]));
entries.forEach(o => groups.get(o.group).push(o));
// 4. Keep only the subarrays that have more than one value
const result = [...groups.values()].filter(group => group.length > 1)
// 5. ...and convert it back to the original format:
    .flatMap(group => [
        { subject: group[0].entry, property: "subject", value: group[0].subject },
        { subject: group[0].entry, property: "field", value: group[0].field },
        ...group.map(o => ({ subject: group[0].entry, property: "content", value: o.content }))
    ]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll start answering the question but we will need to go back and forth so I can better understand what you are looking for.

```js
let data = [
  {subject: 'entry1', property: 'subject', value: 'sport'},
 {subject: 'entry1', property: 'field', value: 'category'},
 {subject: 'entry1', property: 'content', value: 'football'},

 { subject: 'entry4', property: 'subject', value: 'sport' },
  { subject: 'entry4', property: 'field', value: 'category' },
  { subject: 'entry4', property: 'content', value: 'basketball' },

 {subject: 'entry2', property: 'subject', value: 'music'},
 {subject: 'entry2', property: 'field', value: 'category'},
 {subject: 'entry2', property: 'content', value: 'notes'},

 {subject: 'entry3', property: 'subject', value: 'painting'},
 {subject: 'entry3', property: 'field', value: 'category'},
 {subject: 'entry3', property: 'content', value: 'drawing'}
]

let keys = data.map((item, inex) => { return item.subject })

let uniqueKeys = keys.filter((item, index) => { return keys.indexOf(item) >= index })

let propertiesWeCareAbout = ['subject', 'field']

let mappedValues = data.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    acc[item.subject] = {}
    acc[item.subject].values = data.map((subItm, subIndx) => { if (item.subject === subItm.subject) { if (propertiesWeCareAbout.indexOf(subItm.property) > -1) {return subItm.value} }}).filter(Boolean)
    return acc;
}, {})

// this is where I leave you... because I think you need to finish this up yourself. 
// You have all the mapped data you need to solve your question. 
// You now just need to map over the unique keys checking the `mappedValues` data structure for entries that have the same values in the values array. 
// You can rename things if you want. But these are all the parts of the solution laid out.
// p.s. You can remove the 'category' string from the propertiesWeCareAbout array based on the example you provided... and you can simplify what I've provided in a number of ways.

// this is where you map to get just the strings of "entry1" and "entry4" based on the other mapped data provided. Then you can combine data as you said you need to.
let finalListOfEntriesThatNeedToBeMerged = uniqueKeys.map((item, index) => {return item})

console.log(mappedValues)
console.log(finalListOfEntriesThatNeedToBeMerged)
```

This is where you want to start. But the next steps depend on what you are looking to map the data to.

I'm going to focus on this comment next: "entries that share both values for those properties."

Comment: I see where the confusion is. my bad.
I've update my question. Look at the **returned value**

Comment: But you really are trying to transform the data.... Because you're asking how to get entry4 and entry one to be "merged" into one entry.

Comment: the final step would be to transform the data
but first I need to have a middle step where I tell the transformation what need to be transformed, and this is why I added the analysis step into the process

Comment: I've given you all the steps but the final one; I'd like to see you give it a try. Please take time to ask questions and take what I've provided and see if you can solve it.

Comment: I also just want to note: You do not have to take this many steps to solve this. I have laid it out step by step so you better understand the approach. But this can be boiled down into fewer lines and operations.(And dont forget to 'accept' my answer and upvote if it helped you!)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array of triples to an object where `result[propertyString][valueString]` is an array of triples with "property" equal to propertyString and "value" equal to valueString:

```
triples.reduce((acc, triple) => {
    acc[triple.property] = acc[triple.property] || {};
    acc[triple.property][triple.value] = acc[triple.property][triple.value] || [];
    acc[triple.property][triple.value].push(triple);
    return acc;
}, {})
```

You can then search that object for the properties and values you want, and check if there is more than one triple.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash you can groupBy the `subject`, convert to an object, groupBy objects by the new `subject` property and the `field` property, and convert back to an array of items:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map, set, head, flatMap, toPairs, isArray } = _;

const dontCollect = key => ['entry', 'subject', 'field'].includes(key);
const createPropery = (subject, property, value) => ({ subject, property, value });

const fn = flow(
  pr(groupBy, 'subject'),
  pr(map, (g, entry) => ({ // convert to object with the subject as entry
    entry,
    ...g.reduce((r, o) => set(r, o.property, o.value), {}),
  })),
  pr(groupBy, o => `${o.subject}-${o.field}`),
  pr(map, g => g.length > 1 ? _.mergeWith(...g, (a, b, k) => { // merge everything to an object
    if(dontCollect(k)) return a;
    return [].concat(a, b); // convert non entry, subject, or field properties to array if repeated
  }) : head(g)),
  pr(flatMap, ({ entry: subject, ...o }) => // convert back a series of rows
    flow(
      toPairs,
      pr(flatMap, ([property, value]) => isArray(value) ?
        map(value, v => createPropery(subject, property, v))
        :
        createPropery(subject, property, value)
      )
    )(o)
  )
);

const triples = [{"subject":"entry1","property":"subject","value":"sport"},{"subject":"entry1","property":"field","value":"category"},{"subject":"entry1","property":"content","value":"football"},{"subject":"entry4","property":"subject","value":"sport"},{"subject":"entry4","property":"field","value":"category"},{"subject":"entry4","property":"content","value":"basketball"},{"subject":"entry2","property":"subject","value":"music"},{"subject":"entry2","property":"field","value":"category"},{"subject":"entry2","property":"content","value":"notes"},{"subject":"entry3","property":"subject","value":"painting"},{"subject":"entry3","property":"field","value":"category"},{"subject":"entry3","property":"content","value":"drawings"}];

const result = fn(triples);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I first filtered all `property.subject`s and reduced them into a multidimensional array, where each array contains subject values that appeared more then once.

Then I filter all `property.field`s and check if their `property.subject`are equal as well.

Then I create a mapped object (`mergeEntriesBysubjectIndex`) where I get  `{0: true, 1: false, 2: true}` where each key refer to `subjects` indexed values.

In the end, I run on `mergeEntriesBysubjectIndex` and each true index will trigger a new merged entry based on the indexed `subjects`, and new updated array of all triples.

My implementation:

```
/* 
* @description 
* Get an mulitdimensional array, where each inner array represent a list
* of entries with similar value
* 
* @ return [[], [], []]
*/
const subjects = Object.values(
  triples
    .filter(triple => triple.property === "subject")
    .reduce((subjects, entry) => {
      if (subjects[entry.value]) {
        subjects[entry.value].push(entry.subject);
      } else {
        subjects[entry.value] = [];
        subjects[entry.value].push(entry.subject);
      }
      return subjects;
    }, {})
).filter(arr => arr.length > 1);

const fields = triples.filter(triple => triple.property === "field");

/*
* @description
* Create an object based on the "subjects" mulit-dimensional array from before
* Each key represent the index of "subjects", where the value is a boolean * 
* representing a similar "property:field" value 
*/
const mergeEntriesBysubjectIndex = subjects.reduce((filtered, chunk, index) => {
  let values = [];
  chunk.forEach(subject => {
    const obj = fields.find(field => field.subject === subject).value;
    values.push(obj);
  });
  filtered[index] = values.every((val, i, arr) => val === arr[0]);
  return filtered;
}, {});

/*
* @description
* Get an array of subjects value (e.g. "entry1", "entry2")
* and return a new "merged" collection with uniqe objects
* and with the same name for a subject
*/
const mergeEntries = entries => {
  const ent = triples.filter(triple => triple.subject === entries[0]);
  const newContent = triples
    .filter(
      triple => triple.subject === entries[1] && triple.property === "content"
    )
    .map(triple => ({ ...triple, subject: entries[0] }));
  return [...ent, ...newContent];
};

/*
* @description
* return a new updated list of triples without the specified entries
*/
const removeEntriesFromCurrentTriples = entries =>
  triples.filter(triple => !entries.includes(triple.subject));

for (let index in mergeEntriesBysubjectIndex) {
  if (mergeEntriesBysubjectIndex[index]) {
    const mergeEntry = mergeEntries(subjects[index]);
    const updateEntries = [
      ...removeEntriesFromCurrentTriples(subjects[index]),
      ...mergeEntry
    ];
    // The new trasformed triples collection
    console.log('transformed triples:', updateEntries)
  }
}
```